# Implemented using css folded corners

Tags: css

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u6xidqdqaxjjid/1.png?dl=0

Can I use only the SSC to implement such angles in the block?

Do not want to make pictures.

Who knows, please tell me.

Comment: What have you tried already? You can do this with CSS, but the process would be so complicated I don't see it worth the while.

Answer (score 2):

Try a combination of css pseudo elements ([w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)) and css border radius ([w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius)):

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s8a4bnbn/)

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: darkorange;
  width: 300px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.top-bottom,
.left-right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top-bottom:before,
.top-bottom:after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: darkorange;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 12px;
  border: 4px solid darkgreen;
}
.top-bottom:before {
  top: -12px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
}
.top-bottom:after {
  bottom: -12px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}
.left-right:before,
.left-right:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: darkorange;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 12px;
  border: 4px solid darkgreen;
}
.left-right:before {
  left: -12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
  border-right: 0;
}
.left-right:after {
  right: -12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="top-bottom"></div>
  <div class="left-right"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam iusto magnam natus amet in assumenda iure recusandae aspernatur animi blanditiis molestiae sunt nisi temporibus reprehenderit nesciunt doloribus fugit aliquam! Vero!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Great answer.

Comment: @Dzvene Great that you like it. If it is the answer to your question, it would be kind to accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Dzvene Just a short reminder, it would be kind to accept my answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% accurate but a start, you should be able to tweak from here to match the shape you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/e83qygoj/3/

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_bg">   
        <div class="corner one"></div>
        <div class="corner two"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          margin-top:-50px;
}

.box_bg {
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 100px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-border-radius: 20%;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20%;
      border-radius: 20%;
}

.box_bg:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
 }

.corner {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 0 solid transparent;
      border-right: 70px solid transparent;
      border-top: 100px solid red;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
}

.one {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.two {
   margin-left: -70px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```